# Copying data from SQL CE 3.0 to SQL CE 3.5

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I want to copy some data from an SQL CE 3.0 database to an SQL CE 3.5 database within my application (using C#)

Unfortunately, I can't access the old database with the 3.5 engine because it keeps telling me that my 3.0 database was made with an older version.

Can I run the 3.5 engine and the 3.0 engine at the same time?  Can I reference both in the same class library?

How would this work?

Thanks

Comment: You can use 2 class libraries, that each implement the same interface for exmaple, and they can each reference 3.0 and 3.5

Comment: That's what I think I will end up doing.... make this into an answer and if this works, I'll give you credit... not sure if it works yet, though....Don't see why it wouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(String.Format("Data Source={0};Password={1};Persist Security Info=True",dataBasepath,password));
engine.Upgrade();
```

I am not sure, but you cand just upgrade existing database!

Comment: that was my first approach a month ago, but it didn't work for me... upgrading the old database gave me problems using engine.Upgrade().... even after doing the upgrade it wouldn't let me use linq to sql .... but if I reopened the database in Visual Studio, it would THEN allow me to use linq to sql.  Unfortunately, doing it that way won't work with the client machines.  So what I did was upgraded my old skeleton database with Visual studio and replaced the old database with it.  Then through code copy info over from the old one to the new one

Comment: I decided to go back to this... a little history: the last time I tried this I upgraded the database and it STILL wouldn't let me use Linq to SQL unless I opened the database in Visual Studio... but just now I forgot that I could STILL use ADO.NET on it.... so for this solution I went ahead and used the upgrade to 3.5 and just use ADO.NET to get the info I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 class libraries, that each implement the same interface for example, and they can each reference 3.0 and 3.5. This is waht I do in my SQL Server Compact Toolbox, where the same code supports both version 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: ha!!! I'm still trying to do this... for some odd reason my old database needs to be upgraded to be used by SQL CE Engine 3.0, which doesn't make sense.  I used this same library to access it in my older version of my application.  I wonder if it is trying to use my 3.5 engine instead, even though the class library references the 3.0 engine.... something that always puzzled me is why does SQL CE 3.0 show version 9.0.242.0 in Visual Studio

Comment: Unless it is 3.5 format already? Use the SQL Server Compact Toolbox to check.

Comment: The SQL Server Compact Toolbox says **Sql Server Compact edition 3.0/3.1.**    .... and Sql CE Engine 3.0 doesn't have an SQLCEEngine.Upgrade() function.....  I've heard you can use SQLCEEngine.Repair().  Tried that and I get the error **The file that is being referenced is not a SQL Server Compact database file format.**

Comment: You can use the 3.5 SqlCeEngine Upgrade method to upgrade from 3.0 to 3.5.

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing... only issue was I had to use ADO.Net for that part of the application..... it seems that if you upgrade to 3.5 through code, you can't use linq to sql on the upgraded database.....  seeing that this part of my application was a really minute part of the system, I went ahead and upgraded the database and used ADO.NET to transfer information from that database to the new database.